# Printing Pointer Data with Printf in C

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, printf

My understanding is that when you declare a pointer, say `int *a = 5`, `a` is the pointer, and `*a`is the int pointed to - so the `*` indicates you're accessing the pointer data. (And the `&` is accessing the address). Hopefully this is correct?

How come when I'm doing `printf` it doesn't seem to work the way I want?

```
int main()
{
    int *a = 5;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the correct result, which I didn't expect. When I did `*a` instead of `a` in the printf, it failed, which I'm confused with?

Comment: There is a reason this is called **undefined** behaviour. What about the `printf` man-page how to print a pointer did you not understand? And recap about pointers and initialisers.

Comment: What is the meaning of "*the correct result, which I didn't expect*" anyway?

Comment: Are you interested in `a` pointing to a `int 5` or `a` having the address of 5?

Comment: the purpose of this was that i was confused about pointers, and i was just learning. But from the answers + some reading, I think I get the syntax and what it means now.

Comment: I thought that `int *a = 5` was giving `*a` a value of 5, but that's not how the declaration works, and also i need to initialize the ptr first, which were my mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nopes, `int *a = 5;` does not store an `int` value of `5` into the memory location pointed by `a`, the memory location itself is `5` (which is mostly invalid). This is an initialization statement, which initializes the variable `a` which is of type `int *` (a pointer) to `5`.

For ease of understanding, consider the following valid case

```
int var = 10;
int *ptrVar = &var;
```

here, `ptrVar` is assigned the *value* of `&var`, the pointer. So, in other words, `ptrVar` points to a memory location which holds an `int` and upon dereferencing `ptrVar`, we'll get that `int` value.

That said, in general,

```
  printf("%d\n",a);
```

is an invite to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you're passing a pointer type as the argument to `%d` format specifier.

Comment: Thanks, I realized the mistake now, and I got it to work. Is there a way to make `*ptrVar` equal to 10 without doing `int var = 10` first?

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `int *a` does declare `a` to be a pointer. Thus, the declaration

```
int *a = 5;
```

initializes `a` with the value 5. Just like how

```
int i = 5;
```

would initialize `i` with the value 5.

There are very few situations where you would want to initialize a pointer variable with a literal value (other than 0 or NULL). Those would likely be embedded (or otherwise esoteric) applications where certain addresses have a defined meaning on a particular platform.